# How to keep the text of cell label at top when cell's height increases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am increasing cell's height in the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, as a result of it, the `label` is coming centered.
How do make sure that `label` is still at top with the text irrespective of the height of the row?

Comment: Add label on the cell & set its frame as per your requirement.

Comment: I did that but it is still coming centered.
I did that to default textLabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

1. Create a custom label and set it's frame.

   ```
   UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)];
   [cell.contentView addSubView:lbl];
   ```
2. Use a `UITableViewCell` subclass and override `-layoutSubviews`. In this method, you'll want to call `[super layoutSubviews]`.

   ```
   - (void)layoutSubviews {
       [super layoutSubviews];

       CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
       CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
       self.textLabel.frame =  frame;
       self.textLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

While allocating UITableViewCell, you need to do like this..

```
UITableViewCell * cell;

cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:string];
```

At the time of initialization with style: `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` will come.

Hope this will work..

Answer (score 1):

Write Following Code:

```
UILabel *myLable = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
[cell.contentView addSubView: myLable];
```

If Also You want `myLable` fram  is similare to `myLable.text` then write..

```
[myLable sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the position of `textlabel` as it is auto-adjusted.

First option is you need to subclass UITableViewCell and customize textLabel frame.

Another is that you create your own custom label and make textlabel nil. So whenever cell's height will change, your label position will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `autolayout` Top property of `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

set False to "Autoresize Subviews" property of your custom cell...